# Achieving low coupling in a micro-services architecture

Tags: architecture, microservices

In our system, customer details are required in many use cases.
In some use cases, Some services need to validate this data with thirds parties, in other, this data should be sent to other third parties' services in order to create a contract to the customer.

As I see it there are few options to handle it, and they are all bad :(

1. send a query to the customer service (that mean high coupling to it )
2. Listen to all events from the customer service and save all the customers' details as cache in all the services that need that data - (complex solution, many bugs can happen due to sync issues, etc... ).

*I think option 1 is better*, but that means a high coupling of many services to the Customer service...

**Is there any better way?**

Answer (score 0):

As often in architectural considerations, there is probably not a "best" way, but any solution will be a tradeoff with respect to requirements and conditions.

The question of how to share data in a microservices architecture has been discussed for example [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/368279/microservices-and-data-storage) and [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/385346/where-to-store-data-for-microservices-architecture); I also liked [this article](https://hackernoon.com/is-shared-database-in-microservices-actually-anti-pattern-8cc2536adfe4) and [this article](https://auth0.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices-part-4-dependencies/) on the topic.

For your case, I see the following options:

- **each service has a database for the data that it owns**: basically your first option and really the "original" idea of a microservices architecture. Actually, I don't quite agree that this will lead to high coupling, you must however carefully design your interfaces to make them independent of the internal data structures and logic. Smaller services and instead more communication between them is a typical consequence.
- **a single database shared by all services**: this does add more coupling and kind of breaks the idea of a microservices architecture. Could however be an option if you expect very few changes to use cases / data model / database schema etc.
- **an event/subscription model**: you must be very clear what your events are; might become complicated if you have many events and/or many subscribers.
- and finally: **rethink the microservices approach** - for example it might help to combine several single services into one larger service.

The decision should also depend on the expected volumes of data, scalability, frequency of changes.